# php wait till previous function has finished

Tags: php, function, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to create some xml , basically by reading rss feeds and adding to them some custom tags. I've made a function that contains my code, and now i want to call the function several times with different rss urls. Each call will produce a different .xml file.
I use DOMDocument to load and parse the rss, and simple_html_dom to load and parse the link of each rss item to get some content from the html.
Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
load_custom_rss('http://www.somesite.com/rssfeed/articles', 'articles.xml'); 
load_custom_rss('http://www.somesite.com/rssfeed/jobs', 'jobs.xml');
load_custom_rss('http://www.somesite.com/rssfeed/press', 'press.xml');
//up to 20 similar function calls here...

function load_custom_rss($link, $filename){

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($link);

    $newDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    $rss        = $newDoc->createElement('rss');
    $channel    = $newDoc->createElement('channel');
    $newDoc->appendChild($rss);
    $rss->appendChild($channel);

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

        //here is some code to read items from rss xml / write them to new xml document.
        //Code missing for simplicity

        //Next lines used to get some elements from the html of the item's link
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        html->load_file($node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $ret = $html->find('#imgId');       
    }
    $newDoc->formatOutput = true;
    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $newDoc->saveXML());
    fclose($fh);

    unset($doc);
    //unset ALL variables and objects created in this function...
    //........

}//function end
?>
```

My problem is that each call of the function consumes quite an amount of memory, so after the 3rd or 4th call of the function apache throws Fatal Error, as the script consumes memory amount bigger than the memory_limit, even though i unset ALL variables and objects created in the function. If i reduce the function calls to 1 or 2 everything works fine.
Is there any way it could work? I was thinking about each function call waits for the previous to finish before starting, but how could this be done?

Hope somebody could help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this have to be run from apache or can you run it from the command line?  If the latter, you don't have such strict limits on time and memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you want is normal behaviour in php. It's worked through from top to bottom. Each function has to wait, till the previous function has finished. I think you problem is rather the memory-limit within the php.ini. Open the file and search for the directive: `memory_limit` http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit Increase it to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi @faileN, thanks for replying :) I am not allowed to edit the php.ini ;)

Comment: You can also use ini_set function to alter your memory usage. Perhaps that is permitted?

Comment: That would be (in php-code): `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You're unsetting $doc but not $newDoc, try adding

```
unset($newDoc);
```

At the end of that function.

As others have said, the problem is you're leaking memory or exceeding your memory limit; this is nothing to do with waiting until previous code has finished.

Alternatively you could put each call to `load_custom_rss()` into separate requests, so the script calls one and then reloads itself, i.e.

```
$i = $_GET['i'];

if ($i==0)
    load_custom_rss('http://www.somesite.com/rssfeed/articles', 'articles.xml'); 
elseif ($i==1)
    load_custom_rss('http://www.somesite.com/rssfeed/jobs', 'jobs.xml');

... etc ...

else
    die("I'm done");

header("Location: myself.php?i=".($i+1));
```

Your approach to reloading the script would likely be different of course, depending on whether the page needs to render any HTML first.

Comment: Hello @Oliver, thank you for replying!
As i say in my code example i unset all objects created in the function - $newDoc as well. I didn't put all unsets in the code for simplicity.
The script will not be run via any browser, it will be triggered by a third party application (through ajax i think). Do u think your approach is achievable in some way, so that when the script is triggered it will call itself (header() is not the solution here)?

Comment: That would be harder, but possible. I've done something similar before where I have PHP invoke multiple PHP 'child' scripts via the command line via `exec`. That works but might be a slight headache depending on your hosting environment.

See if you can call your script with `exec("php <scriptfilename>")` for starters.